# Remove a specified value from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm setting an array of IDs as "favourites" in localStorage,

```
var favIndex=$favourites.indexOf($titleId);
if(favIndex==-1){
    $favourites.push($titleId);
    $('#fav').addClass('favourited');
}
else{

    $('#fav').removeClass('favourited');
}

var favouritesJson=JSON.stringify($favourites);
localStorage.setItem('favourites',favouritesJson);
console.log(localStorage.getItem('favourites',favouritesJson));
```

If the value is not already in the array it will be added, in the else statement I need to remove $titleId from the array, is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method that remove n elements from the given index:

```
if(favIndex==-1){
    $favourites.push($titleId);
    $('#fav').addClass('favourited');
} else {
    $favourites.splice(favIndex, 1);
    $('#fav').removeClass('favourited');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link array.splice method 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var favoritesIndex = $favourites.indexOf($titleId)

if( favoritesIndex > -1 ) {
    $favourites.splice( favoritesIndex, 1 );
    $('#fav').removeClass('favourited');
}
else{
    $favourites.push($titleId);
    $('#fav').addClass('favourited');
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, don't just post code and expect people to understand. Thanks!